# Перенаправление на другую страницу при обновлении страницы(F5)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

У меня есть компонент, к которому переход осуществляется с помощью browsRouter. Мне нужно, чтобы когда пользователь попытался обновить страницу, его перенаправило на страницу входа, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Извините, мошт че не понимаю, ну а если пользователь уже залогинен, что должно произойти?

Comment: Независимо от того залогинен или не залогинен...на страницу можно попасть, только при this.props.router.push("/url"), а если будет произведено обновление страницы (f5), то нужно сделать redirect на другую страницу

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `localStorage`:

*Login.js*

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
  }

  handleLogin() {
    // doing your login stuff

    localStorage.setItem("approved", "1");
    this.props.router.push("/secret-url"); // success redirect to next page
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
  }
}
```

*SecretComponent.js*

```
class SecretComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkAccess();
  }

  checkAccess() {
    const access = localStorage.getItem("approved");
    if (access && Number(access)) {
      localStorage.setItem("approved", "0");
    } else {
      this.props.router.push("/login"); // redirect to login page
    }
  }
}
```